# Number of solutions of this linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a system of $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns like this.

$x_0*k_{0,0} + x_1*k_{0,1} + x_2*k_{0,2}... = 0$
$x_0*k_{1,0} + x_1*k_{1,1} + x_2*k_{1,2}... = 0$
$x_0*k_{2,0} + x_1*k_{2,1} + x_2*k_{2,2}... = 0$
$...$

The system has the following constraints:

For every $a,b$
$k_{a,b} = -k_{b,a}$

and for every $i$
$0 <= x_i <= 1$

and
$\sum_{i=0}^n x_i = 1$, so technically there are only $n-1$ unknowns.

I want to show that there is always at least one solution (if $n>0$) and that there are only an infinite number of solutions iff there are $a,b$ such that for every $c$
$k_{a,c} = k_{b,c}$
In other words, if there are two rows where the coefficients are identical.

Context: The motivation of this problem is that I want to show that in a rock paper scissor type game, with $n$ strategies that have various payoffs against each other, there exists a unique optimal mixed strategy.
The $k_{a,b}$ coefficients are the payoffs between two strategies, the $x_i$ unknowns are the probabilities assigned to each strategy for the mixed strategy.
The system of equations are the expected payoffs of all pure strategies against the mixed strategy that are not dominated by other pure strategies. All those strategies should have an expected payoff of $0$.

Comment: The system will have a non-trivial solution if dimension is odd.

Comment: Why? And what is a non-trivial solution? Keep in mind that the unknowns have to add up to 1, so you can't have zero everywhere.

Comment: Since you want x_i to be probabilities you want x_i also to be positive right?

Comment: Such a system need not have a solution with positive coordinates

Comment: Wouldn't that contradict Nash's Existence Theorem?